# How should I get related entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to understand how to work with related entities in Hibernate.
There are two related entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    private boolean active;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
    mappedBy = "responsibleUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<GrowBox> growBoxes;
    //def-constructor , getters, setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "growBoxes")
public class GrowBox {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer length;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer width;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer height;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "responsibleGrowBox", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Plant> plants;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "activeGrowBox", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Sensor> sensors;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User responsibleUser;
    //def-constructor , getters, setters
}
```

I have registered mapping using annotations. Hope it is correct. And I want to find box by user Id, but don't know how HQL query should be written. 'Cause there is no "user_id" field in my Box Class. Instead there is "User responsibleUser" field. And smth like this won't work(should not)

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public List<GrowBox> findByUser(Long userId) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hqlQuery = "from GrowBox where user_id =: userId";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hqlQuery);
    List growBoxes = query.getResultList();
    session.flush();
    session.close();
    return growBoxes;
}
```

Comment: look at this thread: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A HQL query would be

```
String hqlQuery = "from GrowBox gb where gb.responsibleUser.id =: userId";
```